# Parse Text CSS into JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, textarea

I just simply want something that will take a textarea full of CSS and turn it into JSON using the CSS JSON method.

```
{
    "selector-1":{
        "property-1":"value-1",
        "property-n":"value-n"
    }
}
```

http://www.featureblend.com/css-json.html

Does anyone know of something that will decode CSS into JSON?  It would also be helpful if it could encode it as well.

Comment: I don't know of any ready-made  solution, but it wouldn't be too difficult to make something (particularly if the CSS is already parsed by the browser).

Comment: It's not really something I wanted to undertake.  IE: dealing with background tags VS background-image I was hoping someone already solved those issues in order to save large amounts of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This js parser has both methods you are looking for.

[CSS JSON parser](https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON)

```
// To JSON
var json = CSSJSON.toJSON(cssString);

// To CSS
var css = CSSJSON.toCSS(jsonObject);
```

Or jQuery plugin parser.

[jQuery parser](http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/)

Example css:

```
div div:first {
  font-weight: bold;
  -jquery: each(function() {alert(this.tagName);})
}

div > span {
  color: red;
}
```

JSON output sent to the callback:

```
{
  'div div:first' : {
    'font-weight' : 'bold',
    '-jquery': 'each(function() {alert(this.tagName);})'
  },
  'div > span' : {
    'color': 'red'
  }
}
```

You can apply css string to an element like this:

```
var cssJSON = '{ "display": "none" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

$("#element").css(obj);
```

Comment: I searched indefatigably to find something like this and I could only come up with bunk.  Thank you.

Comment: After playing with it I am going to write the whole thing, but I appreciate the guy doing a proof of concept... It's just lacking.

Comment: Great. Then maybe you can open source it. That way we will have more options in the future.